# JPQL query containing LIKE converted into criteria

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, criteria

I need to use the **LIKE** operator into an JPA query. I need to use it for types other then String but the JPA criteria API allows me to add only String parameters. I tried using the `.as(String.class)` but something fails and also tried calling the `CAST` function from the underlying `Oracle` that again fails for unknown reasons to me.

I tried writing the query also in JPQL and it works as expected. This is the query:

```
SELECT p from CustomerOrder p where p.id like '%62%'
```

**UPDATE:**

The query must be built in a generic fashion as it is for filtering, so it needs to be created at runtime. On the query that is already created I tried to add the **LIKE** clause like this:

```
query.where(builder.like(selectAttributePath.as(String.class), "%"+filterValue.toString().toLowerCase()+"%"));
```

But this crashes with this exception:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found '(' near line 1, column 156 [select distinct generatedAlias0.id from de.brueckner.mms.proddetailschedact.data.CustomerOrder as generatedAlias0 where cast(generatedAlias0.id as varchar2(255 char)) like :param0]
```

I executed the same query directly to **Oracle** using SQLDeveloper, so it should be sound from this point of view. So the problem is the Hibernate is the issue. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

How can I write this query using JPA Criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by invoking the `'TO_CHAR'` function from the underlying `Oracle DB` and using the **LIKE** operator like for normal **String**'s.

```
query.where(builder.like(selectAttributePath.as(String.class), "%" +filterValue.toString().toLowerCase() + "%")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code, it might require modifications.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<CustomerOrder> cq = cb.createQuery(CustomerOrder.class);
Root<CustomerOrder> order = cq.from(CustomerOrder.class);
cq.where(cb.like(Long.valueOf(order.get(CustomerOrder_.id)).toString(), "%62%"));

TypedQuery<CustomerOrder> q = em.createQuery(cq);
List<CustomerOrder> results = q.getResultList();
```

Comment: already did, the code doesn't compile: Cannot find method 'like(Expression<Long> x, Expression<String> pattern)'. The method signature is: 'like(Expression<String> x, Expression<String> pattern)'

Comment: @user503413 Have you tried casting it explicitly, something like `Long.valueOf(id).toString()`.

Comment: that would probably work, but the topic is part of a broader topic so the criteria is built in the generic fashion hence I will not always know whether it is an ID or something else